# How to set idle PWM output as LOW in timer settings in STM32 board?

Tags: stm32, pwm

I start a PWM output(using Timer1) in a STM32 Nucleo board using HAL as follows:

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
```

And I stop the PWM at an interrupt using HAL as below:

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_IT(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
```

[image]

But when the PWM is not pulsating it outputs 1.8V as indicated in red in above snapshot. What parameter would set it such that the PWM would output zero instead of 1.8V?

Here is Timer 1 settings:

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 40-1;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = PERIOD;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = PERIOD/2;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2State = TIM_BREAK2_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Polarity = TIM_BREAK2POLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Filter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}
```

Comment: PWM mode 2 is low until timer counter reaches compare value. Try PWM mode 2 and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately didnt work.  I also tried TIM1->CNT = 0; after and before. HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_IT.  In my case at each second the PWM starts with an interrupt  and after certain number of pulses ends by HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_IT is called. But remains HIGH after HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_IT is called. I wish to make it LOW instead.

Comment: And PWM output is initially HIGH as well even before  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_IT

Comment: You need to check what the value of CNT is when it stops in debugging. Also, at what moment exactly do you stop? What event? Yes it's high because PWM mode 1.

Comment: I set it to PWM mode 2 and it is still HIGH initally.

Comment: Wait, it's HIGH or 1.8V?

Comment: Sorry I mean 1.5V.

Comment: This is a scope screenshot from my PWM mode 2 implementation (both timers PWM2), as you can see, before the timer kicks in, the pins are at arbitrary levels. Try activating GPIO pulldown and see if it does anything. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ellectroid/STM32F746-Chained-Timers-Demo/main/OscilloscopeScreenshots/TIM3_TIM5_Start.bmp

Comment: But in CubeMX under timer settings it seems its not possible to change them. The dropdown is locked and set to No pull-up pulldown

Comment: Oh sorry I found the settings I will try and let you know

Comment: it has nothing to do with timer. GPIO settings. Where you select GPIO drive speed (slow/fast/very fast)

Comment: Yes thanks it works now. Thanks a lot! So that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When GPIO is configured, but the timer is not running yet, the pin may be in arbitrary state. For example, if you look at my PWM2 implementation (nothing fancy, just a regular PWM2 with custom parameters), you can see before I actually activate the timers (immediately after reset), the pins are in different states (while I was holding reset), there can be some undefined state in your case as well (although 1.5V is a little odd; not sure about that):

[image]

Picture from my Timer demo sketch on [GitHub](https://github.com/ellectroid/STM32F746-Chained-Timers-Demo)

Since you want to have explicit pin state at all times, you should activate GPIO pull-down on a pin in GPIO configuration, it will fix the timer pin state to low when the timer is not actively driving it.